# Merging 2 Pandas dataframes into 1 with permutation of multiple columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, merge

I have two Pandas data frames representing an inventory of items. Both data frames have four columns:

```
df1
id, item, colour, year
1, car, red, 2015
2, truck,, 2016
3, house, blue,
4, car, blue,
5, truck, red, 2015

df2
id, item, colour, year
1, house, blue, 2015
2, truck,, 2015
3, car, blue,
4, house,,
5, car, red, 2015
```

I know that these inventories are likely to represent the same object, so I would like to relate both of these.

For instance,

- df1[1] = df2[5] (3 identique variables)
- df1[4] = df2[3] (2 identique variables)
- df1[3] (house, blue,) is probably the same as df2[1] (house, blue, 2015).

I have 2 main issues: how to do it efficiently, and how to give a reliability to the link.

I've thought of creating a common field which would be a combination of all the columns [item, colour, year] and merge on this. I would get the two first matches above; but they don't have the same reliability. I wonder if there would be an easy way to 'score' this reliability (at the moment I'm thinking of doing two merges, depending on variable availability).
The I would create another common field, with only 2 variables (item, colour), and merge on this. That would give me the link: (house, blue,) and (house, blue, 2015). This would obviously be a weaker link.

Any idea how to do this without merging sequentially? My current plan is to merge with 3 attributes (when they are present), then 2 attributes (there are 3 permutations) on what is left and has at least 2 attributes, and then 1 only. I would give a reliability score to the link based on the number of attributes I used to merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    (df1.values[:, None] == df2.values).sum(2),
    df1.index, df2.index)

matches = df.mask(df.lt(2)).stack()

def f(df):
    i, j = df.name
    return pd.concat([df1.loc[i], df2.loc[i]], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2']).T

matches.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(f).stack().unstack([-2, -1])
```

[image]

Comment: wow, that looks cool! I'm not sure I understand everything (I first got confused because you put df1 right next to df2, but in fact it's the ids that are the result, right?)
Is it possible to have the year as an exact match? (basically 2 cannot be the same as 2)